# String Concatenation and reference

Tags: regex, xslt

I've the below piece of XML. and when I'm running XSLT, output is something else than expected.

```
<toc><tertiaryie>generally, 75/24—75/24/1</tertiaryie>
<secondaryie>Practice Direction, PD1.1/1—PD1.1/9</secondaryie>
<secondaryie>preliminary act</secondaryie>
<secondaryie>collision actions, 75/20</secondaryie>
<secondaryie>failure to lodge, E75/19/32</secondaryie>
</toc>
```

When i'm trying to apply the below xslt.

```
<xsl:template match="tertiaryie">
  <xsl:variable name="tertClassType">
    <xsl:value-of select="@level"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="tertClassTypName">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('tertiaryie-', $tertClassType)"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <div class="tertiaryie">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">

  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[^,\s—[A-Z]+]+">

    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:variable name="range" select="tokenize(.,'—')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="pg" select="tokenize(.,'/')"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',substring(.,1,1)))">

          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($pg[3],'—')">
              <xsl:variable name="range-pg" as="item()*">
                <xsl:for-each select="$range">
                  <xsl:sequence select="tokenize(.,'/')"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:variable>
              <xsl:for-each select="xs:integer($range-pg[3]) to xs:integer($range-pg[6])">
                <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_{
                              if (string(number($range-pg[1]))!='NaN') then 
                              format-number(number($range-pg[1]),'00') 
                              else 
                              $range-pg[1]}/P{string-join($range-pg[position()=(1,2)],'/')}/{.}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="concat(string-join($range-pg[position()=(1,2)],'/'),'/',.)"/>
                </a>
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_{
                        if (string(number($pg[1]))!='NaN') then 
                        format-number(number($pg[1]),'00') 
                        else 
                        $pg[1]}/P{$pg[1]
                        }/{string-join($pg[position()>1],'/')}">
                 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               </a>                            
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains('PD',substring(.,1,2))">

              <a href="{concat('HKWBV1_SEC_',substring-after(substring-before(.,'/'),'PD'),'/PPD',translate(substring-after(.,'PD'),'.','-'))}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </a>

            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <span class="invalid">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>  
              </span>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>

   </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>           
</xsl:template>
```

it is giving me the below output.

```
<div class="tertiaryie"><a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_generally/Pgenerally/">generally</a>, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_75/P75/24">75/24</a>—<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_75/P75/24/1">75/24/1</a></div>
```

where as I want the output as below.

```
<div class="tertiaryie">generally, <a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_75/P75/24">75/24</a>—<a href="er:#HKWBV1_ORD_75/P75/24/1">75/24/1</a></div>
```

please let me know how can I get this. Here all the text is also getting referenced, where as I want only number to get reference.

you can find my entire XSLT here [XSLT](http://pastebin.com/VGMtY8WQ) and XML here [XML](http://pastebin.com/xKuNtm6a)

Comment: Could you add a sample XML input file, please?

Comment: Hi @MarcusRickert, i actually have a big XML file, this is just a line that i gave in the top of my question, and thanks for responding.

Comment: Sorry, it was so small I actually overlooked it. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcusRickert, I've updated the question with links to my documents, sorry that they are big. please take look into it.

Comment: Your shared XSLT is not working property. Please share correct one

Comment: @user2423959: Your XSLT works for AND it gives me exactly the desired output. So it's a processor problem and not an XSLT coding problem.

Comment: Hi @MarcusRickert, it is working but getting applied on text even as i said in my question, iwnt that anchor link only on number not hte text.

Comment: That's what I mean. It's given me the anchors in the right locations. Could you verify, please: http://pastebin.com/ijkTKnsk

Comment: Sorry @MarcusRickert, I had uploaded a wrong XSLT, now i updated the question with correct one. please have a look into it. And thanks for letting me know the result of my previous XSLT. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[\d/]+">
```

This also means you can do away with some complexity further along.

Comment: means do you want to replace your solution with `<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[^,\s—[A-Z]+]+">`

Comment: Hi @Kenney, this is working fine till an extent, but it is not working if the case is like `<secondaryie>Practice Direction, PD1.1/1—PD1.1/9</secondaryie>`

Comment: Well, obviously not ;-) 
It seemed to me that you were selecting everything that _shouldn't_ be replaced, but it's easier to match what _should_ be replaced.

we'd need to establish the exact grammar for these tags.
Here's something that'll match, though it is probably too broad:

`regex="[A-Z\d\.-/]+"`

Answer (score 0):

It took a while since your XSLT is very complex. This is mainly due to the fact that although you use `analyze-string` you don't really take advantage of its strength at all. Instead you do a lot of parsing afterwards which is IMHO very error-prone and difficult to maintain, especially in a chatty language like XSLT.

I would suggest that you change your solution in such a way that you let the regular expression do most of the work.

Replace your `text()` template by the following XSLT excerpt

```
<!-- this template replaces the old match pattern -->
<xsl:template match="text()">

  <!-- build the regular expression -->  
  <xsl:variable name="text_pattern" select="'(.*)'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="delimiter_pattern" select="', '"/>
  <xsl:variable name="range_pattern" select="'(\[?)([A-Z]*)(\d+)([A-Z]*)(/|\.)([A-Z]*\d+[A-Z]*)(/([A-Z]*\d+[A-Z]*))?\]?'"/>

  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$text_pattern}{$delimiter_pattern}{$range_pattern}(—{$range_pattern})?">

    <!-- extract the business values from the expression -->
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:variable name="text_part" select="regex-group(1)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="from_range_openingbracket" select="regex-group(2)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="from_range_1_prefix" select="regex-group(3)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="from_range_1" select="regex-group(4)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="from_range_1_suffix" select="regex-group(5)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="from_range_12_delimiter" select="regex-group(6)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="from_range_2" select="regex-group(7)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="from_range_3" select="regex-group(9)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="to_range_opening_bracket" select="regex-group(11)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="to_range_1_prefix" select="regex-group(12)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="to_range_1" select="regex-group(13)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="to_range_1_suffix" select="regex-group(14)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="to_range_12_delimiter" select="regex-group(15)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="to_range_2" select="regex-group(16)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="to_range_3" select="regex-group(18)"/>

      <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="($from_range_1_prefix = 'PD' or $from_range_1_prefix = '') and $from_range_openingbracket = ''">

          <xsl:value-of select="$text_part"/>

          <xsl:call-template name="format_link">
            <xsl:with-param name="range_1_prefix" select="$from_range_1_prefix"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="range_1" select="$from_range_1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="range_1_suffix" select="$from_range_1_suffix"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="range_12_delimiter" select="$from_range_12_delimiter"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="range_2" select="$from_range_2"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="range_3" select="$from_range_3"/>
          </xsl:call-template>

          <!-- optionally output the second range -->
          <xsl:if test="$to_range_1 != ''">
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="format_link">
              <xsl:with-param name="range_1_prefix" select="$to_range_1_prefix"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="range_1" select="$to_range_1"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="range_1_suffix" select="$to_range_1_suffix"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="range_12_delimiter" select="$to_range_12_delimiter"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="range_2" select="$to_range_2"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="range_3" select="$to_range_3"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:if>

        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>

          <!-- inall other cases it has to be marked invalid -->
          <span class="invalid">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>  
          </span>

        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>          
    </xsl:matching-substring>

    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>           

</xsl:template>

<!-- this template formats one hyperlink -->
<xsl:template name="format_link">
  <xsl:param name="range_1_prefix"/>
  <xsl:param name="range_1"/>
  <xsl:param name="range_1_suffix"/>
  <xsl:param name="range_12_delimiter"/>
  <xsl:param name="range_2"/>
  <xsl:param name="range_3"/>

  <xsl:variable name="suffix">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$range_3 != ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('/', $range_3)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="''"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="range_1_formatted" select="format-number(number($range_1), '00')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="url">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$range_1_prefix = 'PD'">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('sec_', $range_1, '_', $range_1_prefix, $range_1, $range_1_suffix, '-', $range_2, $suffix)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('er:#HKWBV1_ORD_', $range_1_formatted, '/P', $range_1_prefix, $range_1_formatted, $range_1_suffix, $range_12_delimiter, $range_2, $suffix)"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <a href="{$url}">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($range_1_prefix, $range_1, $range_1_suffix, $range_12_delimiter, $range_2, $suffix)"/>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

For further completion of your question it would be good if you created a test input file that contained one representantive of each coding variant that you would like to cover.

Comment: @user2423959: Could you pick your primary answer, please?